# I run into this error when trying to load my json file: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to print out my json file in python, but for some reason the json.load function keeps backfiring on me.

This my json file:

> {"_index":"event-entities-production","_type":"event-entity","_id":"AWZShT9ng6suonapWC9v","_score":1,"_source":{"created_at":"2018-10-08T07:12:36.192Z","updated_at":"2018-10-08T07:12:36.195Z","_created_at":null,"_updated_at":"2018-10-08T07:12:36.196+00:00","country":"India","country_code_2":"IN","country_code_3":"IND","continent":"Asia","region":"Maharashtra","city":"Mumbai","ip":"111.119.214.164","zip":null,"lat":19.469999313354492,"lng":72.80000305175781,"timezone":null,"browser":"Mobile Safari","browser_version":"12.0","browser_version_visible":"Mobile Safari 12.0","os":"iOS","os_version":"12.0","os_version_visible":"iOS 12.0","document_title":null,"screen_name":null,"session_id":"SESSION-ab8c1f814bdb737fa92c65a26bad55312529fcf5","app_name":null,"app_package":null,"app_version":null,"device":"iPhone","device_id":null,"device_type":"smartphone","device_brand":"Apple","model":null,"manufacturer":null,"viewport_width":320,"viewport_height":568,"viewport_dimensions":"320x568","sdk_version":"0.5.0","api_version":null,"language":null,"page_title":"NA","referrer":"https://www.mistay.in/hotels-in-mumbai/?checkin_date=2018-10-09&checkin_slot=1&slot_count=1&guest_count=2&room_count=1","referrer_domain":"www.mistay.in","referrer_path":"/hotels-in-mumbai/","referrer_query":"checkin_date=2018-10-09&checkin_slot=1&slot_count=1&guest_count=2&room_count=1","referrer_protocol":"https","referrer_type":"direct","referrer_keyword":null,"referrer_type_name":null,"referrer_keyword_position":null,"source":"web-sdk","current_url_domain":"www.mistay.in","current_url_path":"/hotels-in-mumbai/hotel-sai-palace-inn/","current_url_protocol":"https","current_url_query":"checkin_slot=1&checkin_date=2018-10-09&guest_count=2&slot_count=1&room_count=1","current_url":"https://www.mistay.in/hotels-in-mumbai/hotel-sai-palace-inn/?checkin_slot=1&checkin_date=2018-10-09&guest_count=2&slot_count=1&room_count=1","event_ts":"2018-10-08T07:12:36.192+00:00","is_anonymous_user":null,"is_known_user":null,"traffic_source":null,"traffic_source_type":null,"utm_source":null,"utm_medium":null,"utm_account":null,"utm_keyword":null,"utm_content":null,"utm_campaign":null,"profile_id":"e13488787a1512e635e28e9c9c9a6e7c84c8b1aa006b4ed9a85eec95c4154b22","profile_list_id":4,"profile_key":null,"uuid":"135ed264-3111-4b1d-a0a2-ba7e7faacb2d","event_name":"visited_hotel","account_id":4,"event_list_id":13,"__from_web":null,"__from_upload":null,"__file_upload_id":null,"__from_ios":null,"__from_android":null,"__from_device_id":null,"__client_ts":null,"__is_uploaded":null,"__uploaded_ts":null,"json_0":{},"json_1":{},"json_2":{},"json_3":{},"json_4":{},"json_5":{},"json_6":{},"json_7":{},"json_8":{},"json_9":{},"json_10":{},"json_11":{},"json_12":{},"json_13":{},"json_14":{},"json_15":{},"json_16":{},"json_17":{},"json_18":{},"json_19":{},"json_20":{},"json_21":{},"json_22":{},"json_23":{},"json_24":{},"json_25":{},"json_26":{},"integer_0":4,"integer_1":4,"integer_2":null,"integer_3":null,"integer_4":null,"integer_5":null,"integer_6":null,"integer_7":null,"integer_8":null,"integer_9":null,"integer_10":null,"integer_11":null,"integer_12":null,"integer_13":null,"integer_14":null,"integer_15":null,"integer_16":null,"integer_17":null,"integer_18":null,"integer_19":null,"integer_20":null,"integer_21":null,"integer_22":null,"integer_23":null,"integer_24":null,"integer_25":null,"integer_26":null,"float_0":null,"float_1":null,"float_2":null,"float_3":null,"float_4":null,"float_5":null,"float_6":null,"float_7":null,"float_8":null,"float_9":null,"float_10":null,"float_11":null,"float_12":null,"float_13":null,"float_14":null,"float_15":null,"float_16":null,"float_17":null,"float_18":null,"float_19":null,"float_20":null,"float_21":null,"float_22":null,"float_23":null,"float_24":null,"float_25":null,"float_26":null,"datetime_0":"2018-10-09T00:00:00.000+00:00","datetime_1":null,"datetime_2":null,"datetime_3":null,"datetime_4":null,"datetime_5":null,"datetime_6":null,"datetime_7":null,"datetime_8":null,"datetime_9":null,"datetime_10":null,"datetime_11":null,"datetime_12":null,"datetime_13":null,"datetime_14":null,"datetime_15":null,"datetime_16":null,"datetime_17":null,"datetime_18":null,"datetime_19":null,"datetime_20":null,"datetime_21":null,"datetime_22":null,"datetime_23":null,"datetime_24":null,"datetime_25":null,"datetime_26":null,"string_0":"https://www.mistay.in/hotels-in-mumbai/?checkin_date=2018-10-09&checkin_slot=1&slot_count=1&guest_count=2&room_count=1","string_1":"www.mistay.in","string_2":null,"string_3":"Hotel Sai Palace Inn","string_4":"1","string_5":"1","string_6":"2","string_7":"1","string_8":"1970","string_9":null,"string_10":"Syscon Infoway Pvt.Ltd.","string_11":"-","string_12":null,"string_13":null,"string_14":null,"string_15":null,"string_16":null,"string_17":null,"string_18":null,"string_19":null,"string_20":null,"string_21":null,"string_22":null,"string_23":null,"string_24":null,"string_25":null,"string_26":null,"text_0":null,"text_1":null,"text_2":null,"text_3":null,"text_4":null,"text_5":null,"text_6":null,"text_7":null,"text_8":null,"text_9":null,"text_10":null,"text_11":null,"text_12":null,"text_13":null,"text_14":null,"text_15":null,"text_16":null,"text_17":null,"text_18":null,"text_19":null,"text_20":null,"text_21":null,"text_22":null,"text_23":null,"text_24":null,"text_25":null,"text_26":null,"boolean_0":null,"boolean_1":null,"boolean_2":null,"boolean_3":null,"boolean_4":null,"boolean_5":null,"boolean_6":null,"boolean_7":null,"boolean_8":null,"boolean_9":null,"boolean_10":null,"boolean_11":null,"boolean_12":null,"boolean_13":null,"boolean_14":null,"boolean_15":null,"boolean_16":null,"boolean_17":null,"boolean_18":null,"boolean_19":null,"boolean_20":null,"boolean_21":null,"boolean_22":null,"boolean_23":null,"boolean_24":null,"boolean_25":null,"boolean_26":null,"array_0":[],"array_1":[],"array_2":[],"array_3":[],"array_4":[],"array_5":[],"array_6":[],"array_7":[],"array_8":[],"array_9":[],"array_10":[],"array_11":[],"array_12":[],"array_13":[],"array_14":[],"array_15":[],"array_16":[],"array_17":[],"array_18":[],"array_19":[],"array_20":[],"array_21":[],"array_22":[],"array_23":[],"array_24":[],"array_25":[],"array_26":[]}}

```
import json


f2 = open('sample.json', 'w')


def file_write_from_head(fname, nlines):
        from itertools import islice
        with open(fname) as f:
                for line in islice(f, nlines):
                        f2.write(line)

file_write_from_head('events.json', 1)

with open("sample.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: add the json file also as code with indentation. Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the specific problem you have, I suggest 1) move the imports outside the function 2) open the writing file `f2` inside the function, adding the outfile name as an extra argument would be best. 3) remember to close the file before opening it again!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll modify this post, hold on

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: @PhxDev, the error message is in the title

Comment: it's wrong to post error messages in titles Teju. Use the yellow background or code format to post error, and definitely json and other files in code format.

Comment: I apologise, I'll add the error message to my body. Also, I tried out @alec_djinn's solution and it doesn't seem to be throwing any errors anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found that make your code work was that you forgot to close the reading file.

Therefore you need to do:

```
f2.close()
```

after

```
file_write_from_head('events.json', 1)
```

You can read more about [close](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm).

Your full code snippet will look the following:

```
import json


f2 = open('sample.json', 'w')


def file_write_from_head(fname, nlines):
    from itertools import islice
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in islice(f, nlines):
            f2.write(line)

file_write_from_head('events.json', 1)

f2.close()

with open("sample.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, I think this was definitely the issue :)